# Prove that $\forall x\subset M, \exists y\in M (x\subseteq y)$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let $M$ be a transitive proper class satisfying ZF. Prove that
\begin{equation}
\forall x \subset M\left(\exists y\in M\left(x\subseteq y \right)\right)  \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}
**My progress**

I can prove that if $M$ is transitive, $M$ satisfies $(*)$ and Comprehension Scheme, then $M$ satisfies ZF. Particularly I used $(*)$ to prove $M$ satisfies Replacement, Power, Pairing, Union and Infinity. Thus I think I must use all of them to prove the inverse, but unclear how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea, in my mind, is to "overshoot": don't try to get a set which is "close to $x$" in any sense, but rather look for something so big that everything in $x$ is guaranteed to enter it.

I don't want to fully give away the problem, but here's a hint: if $x$ is a **set** and $M$ is a **proper class**, then the elements of $x$ have bounded rank in the sense of $M$. Can you think of a set in $M$ which contains all the elements of $M$ with rank some fixed ordinal (or rather, with rank *at most* some fixed ordinal)?

---

Note: The statement is of course false if we replace "$\subset$" by "$\in$" - e.g. we may not even have $\mathcal{P}(\omega)=\mathcal{P}(\omega)^M$, but clearly any $x\in\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is a subset of $M$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a bit more why elements of $x$ should have bounded rank in the sense of $M$? Perhaps this is where it matters to me, since I could not think of any useful fact about proper classes.

Comment: @thbl2012 There's only set-many of them, and $M$ is a proper class. The map sending an element of $x$ to its rank in the sense of $M$ can't be cofinal in the ordinals.